# How to force Angular2 to re-create components each time I show them

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-routing, ng2-bootstrap

In our angular2 Typescript application, we use router.
Our components are pretty generic and their behavior changes dramatically based on parameters, which they get from router.

The application is in early stage development and the behavior I'm referring to has been observed recently. I'm not sure if it is because of a change in code or a breaking change in one of the libraries.

Consider a component named `List`. it gets some information from the context (route, wrapping component, etc) such as the entity type it should display.

Now when I change the route, the `List` components is not re-instantiated, but its parameters are updated. Since I use these parameters in `ngOnInit` to setup the component, the later changes will have no effect.

I know I can use change detection to work around this problem, but I rather not to. The reason is that this will make it much more easier for the developers to introduce regression bugs (such as: goto People list, then do something, goto Orders list, something is there that shouldn't be) which are much more difficult to discover, test and reproduce. They are much more probable to leak into production.

How can I force angular to re-create the List component when the route changes.

More observations: In router, if I navigate to a route that does not show the List component and then return to the List, the component is re-instantiated.

Comment: There used to be `routerCanReuse` in late alphas, but not sure what happen to it... Seams it's not implemented in router 3.x, check https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9811

Answer (score 1):

subscribe to the active route params; it is an observable

Answer (score 1):

You can, instead of subscribe, use the `async` pipe to show the Observable last value.

doc: [Pipes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html)

Answer (score 0):

When Router navigates to a new route, it will compare the existing component tree to the new component tree, destroying no longer needed components, creating non-existent needed components, and re-using instances of any still needed components. If you are using a one-and-the-same route and then manually extracting suffixStuff from the full url string, angular won't notice changes in suffixStuff and will not re-create the component. If you use a route that properly declares its suffixStuff so that angular will notice it (an **active route param** per Sameh's answer), angular will notice and re-create the still needed component.

Even so, here is a case to consider. For example, the List component's oninit gets the active route params and performs one read from a database to setup the component. We let the user click things on that component to create, update, delete records in the database. So when those actions have completed, we want to do a reread from the database to show the user the result (it's good practice to only display ACID data, no?). We will naturally reach for our readAndSetup code which is incorrectly living in the oninit method, and attempt some form of page reload or reroute, and will face the issue where back-to-back navs to an identical route (active params and all) will re-use the entire existing component tree.

What we should do instead is **separate the setup code from oninit.** Oninit will get the active route params, make and remember a formedDbQuery from them, then call a separate this.readFromDb method which uses the remembered formedDbQuery. This way a reread doesn't require re-creating the component (calling oninit), we simply call this.readFromDb after an action completes.